# Django Rest Framework Serializer - return related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a one-to-one relationship with a main model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class AggregatedStats(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True)
    followers_30d = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
```

I have written the following serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'followers']

class AggregatedStatsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    username = UserSerializer(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = AggregatedStats
        fields = ['followers_30d', 'username']
```

I am trying to return the `username` from the `User` model, but whatever I try to get it, the best I can do is get the hyperlinked related field from user, but not the actual "username" attribute. How would you return this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a field and return it:

```
class AggregatedStatsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    username = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = AggregatedStats
        fields = ['followers_30d', 'username']

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id.username
```